# React-Redux single reducer/middleware for all tabular data

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have several React components (views) that displays tabular data. Now I want to incapsulate the code for querying/sorting/updating data in a tables into a separate component that can be used in my Views. Visible part is not a problem for me, but how can I make a component that can be used in redux store?

```
// Reducer 1
const emptyPart1 = {data: {id: 1, rows[]}}; // id is one more possible way to find data object
export function part1(state = emptyPart1, action){
    switch(action.type) {
    }
    return state;
}
// Reducer 2
const emptyPart2 = {data: {id: 2, rows[]}};
export function part2(state = emptyPart2, action){
    switch(action.type) {
    }
    return state;
}
const reducers = {
    part1, part2
};

const store = createStore(
    combineReducers(reducers)
);
```

After created store, I want to generate some action that should fill part1's data with rows:

```
store.dispatch({type: ACTION_FILL_DATA, data: store.getState().part1.data});
```

Here I am using a reference to data object. This object will never be recreated, but only its rows will be changed

I want to have some external reducer/middleware, that *is not a parent* for reducer1/2 that will process ACTION_FILL_DATA action, and will part1.data with rows.

How to make it?

Comment: Did you mean you need a data processing function before the action reaches store? Like you said, a middleware will work, what's the problem?

Comment: @StanleyLuo, I need to modify data in a store. Middleware has an access to store, dispatch and action. I need to make this: middleware()->store.state = newstate. I didnt found any docs  how to change state by middleware

Comment: Middleware should not change the store directly, in fact, only actions can mutate the store state. In your case, you could prepare the data in a middleware, and then dispatch an action in middleware which can populate data in store

Comment: This will need me to add specific action handler into every reducer that has data table access. I want to remove it and put into external code component